# Android Studio. Layout preview. Long initialization

Tags: android-studio, gradle, layout, module, preview

I need help to solve the problem with Android Studio. Preview of layout does not initialize.
Gradle version: 8.0
Android plugin: 8.0.2

I have already tried using various solutions but none helped.
I tried to uninstall Android Studio, to clear gradle caches, to delete my project and so on (deleted everything related with Android Studio)

I thought that problem related to a large app module and I tried to delete dependencies and all layouts - without results.

Also I tried to rewrite build.gradle (:app) (to change some line) - without result

Only only thing that helped me somehow - to change plugin id("com.android.application") to id("ommonAndroid"). After that preview loaded.

This mean that problem related to app module which is not "feature module" (P.S. My project has a lot of modules, however, problem exists only in app module.

What is the problem related to and how to solve it?

My project has a lot of modules, however, problem exists only in app module